# Abaqus scripts on university server

Tags: python, abaqus

It's the first time I'm trying to run scripts on the Abaqus server from my university. The IT team provided me the credentials to access the server, but they don't know how to run scripts from there. I'm using Putty to connect to the server, and Filezilla to transfer files.
I tried to run Python scripts from the work directory on the server, but this error came out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SMAPylModules/SMAPylDriverPy.m/src/driverEnv.py", line 324, in envRunFile
  File "/home/gd00357/abaqus_v6.env", line 208, in <module>
    raise 'Cannot find the graphics configuration environment file (graphicsConfig.env)'
```

I couldn't find any documentation on how to run Python scripts, I hope it's possible in some way.
How could I solve that error?

EDIT:
Ok, apparently remote servers don't support any scripts that make use of the GUI.
Now my question is: how do I import a model as input file (.inp) using a Python script? Is there a way that avoids that a Python script uses the GUI?

Comment: Can you update your question to show us the command you are using to run Abaqus?

Comment: To run Python scripts without GUI I simply use:

`abaqus cae noGUI=script.py`

But it's not possible to do that when I'm using external servers, apparently, because my script rely on the GUI (it opens a .cae file and works on it)

Comment: You can copy and paste the `abaqus_v6.env` with necessary modifications to the working directory and run for other applications. In most cases `CAE` scripts can't be run in the cluster. But one can generate the `*.inp` files locally and run them in the cluster with `abaqus j=<job-name> inp=<*.inp>`

Comment: Alright, that's what I thought. I would like to perform some sensitivity studies (MC, screening methods) that require quite a lot input files. Basically I should import the original input file, change some parameters to create a new one to be passed to a script that runs it.
Is there a quick way to seek for some specific words (like `Theta=X`) in the imported `.inp` file and change them? And what's the best way to import files? I tried with `.read()`, but then I don't know how to search through the lines

Comment: One way to do it would be with the help of `*PARAMETER` keyword available in abaqus. We can give the values of a particular variable at the top of the `*.inp` file and replace the corresponding value inside the input file with the `variable name`. It's better to do this locally and generate `n` required input files and submit them.

Comment: Ok, right now I'm just trying to do with this:
        `inputFile=open('Job.inp','r')
        outputFile=open('Modified Input'+'_RUN'+str(run)+'_LEVEL'+str(r)+'.inp','w')`
        (I'm iterating over "run" and "r" \n)
        `for line in inputFile:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            number_of_lines += 1
            if number_of_lines == XXX
                    line = line.replace('YYY','ZZZ')`
It's not general, I still have to work on it, but it actually writes new input files. Now I just have to find a way to run jobs automatically given an input file.

Comment: I tried `*PARAMETER*` for other studies, but now I'm dealing with randomly generated values to perform some sensitivity analysis

Comment: Something funny it's happening with the new input file I generate:
`for line in inputFile:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            if ...  
            outputFile.write(line)`
The thing is that when I try to import this `.inp` file, this error comes:
`NoKeywordsDefinedError`. If I copy what's in this new `.inp` file in the old one, somehow it works. I guess I'm changing some keywords and Abaqus doesn't recognize them: should I specify something when I write the new file to give it the same extension as the old one?

Answer (score 0):

Abaqus has some built-in tools for scripting parametric studies.

Please read about parametric studies in the [Abaqus manual here](https://help.3ds.com/2020/english/dssimulia_established/simacaeanlrefmap/simaanl-c-scriptparstudies.htm?contextscope=all).